# sqlalchemy query get elements that match list of elements

Tags: python, flask

I have some models

```
Gif : id, tags (backref Tag)  
Tag : id
```

and I'm looking for the query to get all the gifs that match with a list of tags.
For example :

```
gif1 = Gif(1 , [1,2,3,4])  
list_tags = [1,2]
```

The query I'd like to use is something like :

```
Gif.query.filter(list_tags in Gif.tags).all()
```

Here's my classes and tables :

```
gifwithtags = db.Table('gifwithtags',
                    db.Column('gif_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
                           'gif.id'), primary_key=True),
                       db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
                           'tag.id'), primary_key=True)
                       )
class Gif(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tags = db.relationship(
        "Tag",
        secondary=gifwithtags,
        backref=db.backref("gifs", lazy="dynamic")
    ) 
class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

which is suppose to return [gif1]

Thank you all for your help !

Comment: How are the tags stored? Are you using a DB array type (like Postgres supports)?

Comment: My stack is Flask + SQLAlchemy + Postgres. I create my model via    class Tag(db.Model): id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

Comment: But are you storing tags in a Postgres array column type? Might help if you include a minimal version of your `Gif` class definition.

Comment: No I'm not. I'll give you my class definition.

Comment: Put the code in your question, indented and all that.

Comment: okay I edited my question.